# Change Material Button Theme in Dark Mode

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-button, android-dark-theme, android-studio-4.2

Please Help Me.

While changing the theme from light mode to dark mode. How do I change the button's theme from filledbutton to outlinedbutton?

I saw an app from play store. Here I noticed that the buttons theme is changing:

This is LIGHT MODE :

[image]

This is DARK MODE :

[image]

I want to change the buttons theme like this. Can anybody tell how to do that?

Any help would be appreciated

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `materialButtonStyle` attribute in your theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.*">
   ...
   <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/CustomButton</item>
</style>
```

Then in a light theme use `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button` as parent:

```
<style name="CustomButton" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
  ...
</style>
```

and in the `values-night` directory use the `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton` as parent:

```
<style name="CustomButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton">
   ...
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

use " androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton "this instead of " Button" this it will automatically changes with the UI theme.
[Please check Image here for better Understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUd15.png)